# Blazor Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService task cancelling

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a blazor .net core 3.1 app that is using Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService.  Sometimes, when first visiting the page, getting data will get a task cancelation.

```
protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (!firstRender) return;
    var results = await _localStorage.GetItemAsStringAsync("MyData");
    //Do amazing logic
}
```

If this happens, a simple refresh in the browser will fix it.  This is a bad solution for the end-user.  Putting a try-catch around _localStorage.GetItemAsStringAsync returns this:

> Error reading local  System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A
> task was canceled.    at
> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeWithDefaultCancellation[T](String
> identifier, Object[] args)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if (!firstRender) return;

Note: The `firstRender` parameter is evaluated to true only on the first rendering. Thus, except of the first rendering, your method will always returns. Is that what you want.

Your method signature should be:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
```

That is how you perform async code. The return type should be `Task`, not `void`. If you don't use Task, Blazor cannot know when the method has completed, thus the exception.

Note: The OnAfterRender(Async)(bool firstRender) pair is usually used to initialize JS object, and the call to the initialization should occur only once, after your App has been rendered. This is how you should call your JS inits:

```
if (firstRender)
{
   // Call JS inits
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//protected override async void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
```

The rest is pretty much OK.